# How can I add a shadow (like the attached example) under a LinearLayout element?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I am an absolute beginner in Android development and I have the following problem:

How can I insert something like a shadow under a **LinearLayout** component into my XML activity definition?

I want to obtain something like this:

[image: example image]

As you can see in the previous image, under the first linear layout (the one that contains the menu and the **April 2017** date) there is a shadow.

What is the standard way to implement this effect?

This is the code of the linear layout under which I want to add this effect:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFD54F"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/colosseumIcon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/HeaderTextStyle"
        android:text="Pasta From Rome" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shadow is done "automatically" by the android system starting in Lollipop. All you have to do is define the view elevation. Meaning, the view is higher on the Z-axis than the view below (or under) it and should drop a shadow on top of it.

For that simply add following on the XML

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```

Adjust the value as you need.

Comment: Cool and there is some further way to define the color and the intensity of this shadow?

Comment: Not using the native implementation. The elevation will vary the dissipation of the shadow based on a global illumination. But that's it. If you try on a black background there won't be anything. http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/implementing-material-design-in-your.html

Comment: Just take notice you won't be able to support older devices that way. So maybe add that for a v21 layout, and for older devices use a shadow image.